# rqt loading with requested perspective

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm having a problem with `roslaunch rqt_gui rqt_gui`. When I launch this command in terminal, only upper bar appears, then it disappears and appears again in different place, but the rqt_gui itself does not launch eventually. I believe it's connected to some plugin I wrote, though there are no error msgs in terminal. Is it possible to somehow run rqt_gui with requested perspective?  I'd like to run rqt_gui with default perspective and try adding my plugin again, to see if it is the cause of my problem - now I'm not able to do anything in rqt.

Thanks in advance,

da-na

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79141/rqt-loading-with-requested-perspective/) by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2013-09-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, I believe you just put typo `rosrun` as `roslaunch`; `roslaunch`ing `rqt_gui` that doesn't have `launch` files shouldn't do anything.

You might want to look at `help` by `$ rqt -h`, that says a few options available regarding perspective:

```
  -p PERSPECTIVE, --perspective PERSPECTIVE
                        start with this named perspective
  --perspective-file PERSPECTIVE_FILE
                        start with a perspective loaded from a file
:  
  --list-perspectives   list available perspectives
```

If you want to reset all settings from previous runtime, run `$ rqt --clear-config`. Again from help:

```
  --clear-config        clear the configuration (including all perspectives and plugin settings)
```

Finally, you can ignite `rqt_gui` by just `rqt` as I did in the above.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on 2013-09-16**:
Hey!
Simply typing rqt doesn't work for me (there's a msg in terminal saying haven't found rqt command). But I typed "roscd rqt_gui/src" and then "./rqt_gui --clear-config" as you suggested.

It worked :) Thank you

Could anyone put this on tutorial page?

**Comment by [Gianluigi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3593/gianluigi/) on 2013-10-08**:
Hi. It worked also for me. In my case I had two click twice on the icon of my plugin for making it appear.
Many thanks.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-10-08**:
@da-na looks like you're on fuerte where `rqt` command isn't there yet.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-07-02**:
@130s where does rqt save perspectives that can be called with the -p option?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-07-02**:
#q53861 might help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

And you can make smt like this in .launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node name = "my_rqt_dashboard" pkg = "rqt_gui" type = "rqt_gui" respawn = "false" output = "screen" args = "--perspective-fila $(find my_pkg_with_rqt_config)/rqt_config/my_dashboard.perspective"/>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Edward](https://answers.ros.org/users/29319/edward/) with karma: 76 on 2018-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2020-02-04**:
a small typo there
`--perspective-fila` should be  `--perspective-file`